# How to add key and value dynamically and call the procedure in java (Oracle ADF)

Tags: java, oracle-adf

```
    ViewObject VO = getViewObjectFromAMImpl("EOView2", "AppModuleDataControl");
    Row[] selectedRows = VO.getFilteredRows("tSelect", true);
    int counter = 0;
    ADFContext adfCtx = ADFContext.getCurrent();
    SecurityContext secCntx = adfCtx.getSecurityContext();
    String _user = secCntx.getUserName();
    //Date vDate = getMinDate();
    java.sql.Timestamp startDate = null;
    for (Row r : selectedRows) {
        startDate = (java.sql.Timestamp) r.getAttribute("StartDate");
        if ("E".equals(r.getAttribute("SrcType"))) {
            r.setAttribute("Type","S");
            r.setAttribute("UpdatedBy", new Date());
            r.setAttribute("LastUpdateDate", new Date());
            counter++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("printing count"+counter);
    if (counter == 0) {
        
        JSFUtils.addFacesErrorMessage((String) JSFUtils.resolveExpression("No records Approved."));
    } else {
        Commit();
        JSFUtils.addFacesInformationMessage((String) JSFUtils.resolveExpression(" records Approved successfully."));
       
        AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(hearderTableBind);
    }
    approvePopup.cancel();
```

From the above code i will get the selected rows with key and value pair. I want to add those rows ( Key and Value) to a list and i need to call the procedure. Could you please tell me which is the best possible way to achive this.

I want to call the procedure with key and value pair( Multiple values will come)

Comment: Tell us your exact JDev version, please!

The code you show does not create key-value pairs. It's just changing some rows and committing the changes.

Why do you need to call a procedure with key-value pairs?

Comment: Version is 12.2.1.4.0. From the aobe code i will traverse through the loop and i will get the id and Status  now I want to add the each row to a MAP and I want to call the procedure by using the MAP.(some time i will get more than 1000 rows )

Comment: Data will be like this
101 123456 100050123 Car 12 03 03 98765
101 123456 100050123 Car 12 03 03 98765
101 123456 100050123 Car  12 03 03 98765
101 123456 100050123 Car 12 03 03 98765
101 123456 100050123 Car 12 03 03 98765
101 123456 100050123 Car 12 03 03 98765
To simplify in the UI  i will write query to get distinct  records only so i will get one record. When i am trying to approve it will approve all the  6 records. When i am trying to do in java it is throwing error too many object error. Could you please suggest some approach.

Comment: So you want to do this after the commit of the changes?

Comment: I will pass the key and value to the procedure it will save and will return the parameter either "Success" or  "Fail"

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. Do you want to call the procedure after the commit?

Comment: Before commit i need to call the procedure

Answer (score 0):

You should read the doc at
https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/developer-tools/adf/12.2.1.4/develop/extending-business-components-functionality1.html#GUID-B93C7B79-73C9-4434-B12E-A7E23479969A
However, I fail to understand why you need to call a pl/sql procedure at all.

You should be able to do everything in ADF or call a procedure directly without iterating over the data just to set some values.

It's not a good idea to change values in ADF, then call a procedure and assume that the framework somehow knows the changes. The procedure runs in the DB in a different transaction. ADF doesn't know about changes done in the function. The function doesn't know about the changes done in ADF until you post them to the DB.

Comment: Hi Timo Hahn thankyou for giving reply  
. Id, Number, Id_num,Item_name,....
 101,121032,100060175,Car,12,03,03,78908;101,121032,100060175,Car,12,03,03,78908; 101,121032,100060175,Car,12,03,03,78908;101,121032,100060175,Car,12,03,03,78908
101,121032,100060175,Car,12,03,03,78908;101,121032,100060175,Car,12,03,03,78908
--101,121033,100060185,Car,12,03,03,78908;101,121033,100060185,Car,12,03,03,78908 
 101,121033,100060185,Car,12,03,03,78908 -;101,121034,100060200,Car,12,03,03,78908
101,121034,100060200,Car,12,03,03,78908;101,121034,100060200,Car,12,03,03,78908

Comment: From the above sample data i will distinct so i will get three records for  id 101. I will use checkbox in the table. i will select 101,121032 records and i will click on Approve. In the UI we will see only one record but back end we have 6 records with that combination .So I want to approve all 6 records. How to achieve this. In which way it is better please suggest your idea.

Comment: As I said, you can do this directly in ADF. Once you know what to look for (in your case, the ID), you can use another VO using a query like select distinct ... to get all rows you want to approve the iterator over them and approve them. As long as you are not talking about >1000 rows, there is nothing more to do. If you have more rows, you need to tune the VO.

Comment: Hi Timo,
I have  a list , and i want to pass that list as input paramater to strored procedure. While executing the stored procedure we will use set method.
                    st.setNull(1, 12);
                    st.setInt(2, caseId);
                    st.setString(3, billbackType); like this way. How to set array type here. Could you please help me on this.

Comment: Look at https://vijaysadhu.blogspot.com/2013/01/pass-array-to-stored-procedure-adf.html or http://visionadf.blogspot.com/2017/10/working-with-plsql-procedures-in-adf-bc.html

Comment: Hi Timo Hahn,
 Getiing the below error 
java.sql.SQLException: Fail to construct descriptor: Unable to resolve type. Type was there in DB

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Fail to construct descriptor: Unable to resolve type "edi_cc_list_rec_type_test"
at oracle.sql.TypeDescriptor.getTypeDescriptor(TypeDescriptor.java:1003)
 at oracle.sql.StructDescriptor.isValidObject(StructDescriptor.java:100)
 at oracle.sql.StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(StructDescriptor.java:123)
 at oracle.sql.StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(StructDescriptor.java:83)

Comment: Looks like you have an error in your implementation. Nothing I can do. Check if you followed the blog posts

Comment: Hi timo Hahn,
I have created view object and through bean i am applying where clause
whereClause = whereClause + "lpad(Idval,14,'0') = " + Idval; when i did vo.executeQuery(); getting row count as zero eventhough we have records in the DB. Could you please suggest me on this why it is getting row count as zero

Comment: Nobody can help you as nobody knows the DB you use. It can't be that hard to print the whole query from the VO and run it against the DB to see what and why it is different.